# Select query with prefix on all column elements

Tags: mysql, laravel

Is it possible to create a database query in which I add a prefix to every single
column of a table. Because the tables unfortunately have "too many" columns I
would like to avoid assigning an alias to every single column.

**Goal:**
`select table1.*, table2` Will output: `table1_id, table_1_name, table2_id, table_2_name, ...`

Is this possible?

That is my approach:

```php
$data = DB::connection('mysql_wp')->table('wp_posts as p')
  ->selectRaw('p.*, m.*')
  ->join('wpao_metas as m', 'm.post_id', '=', 'p.ID')
  ->get();
        
dd($data);
```

But i didnt work. I got columnnames without prefixe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper function to alias the corresponding columns.

```php
public function getColumnAliases(string $table, string $prefix = null): array
{

    $prefix = $prefix ?? $table . "_";

    return array_map(function ($column) use ($table, $prefix) {

        return $table . "." . $column . " AS " . $prefix . $column;

    }, \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table));
}
```

Then in your `select(...)` query:

Instead of ❌:

`->selectRaw('p.*, m.*')`

Use this ✅:

```php
->select(
    array_merge(
        $this->getColumnAliases("wp_posts"),
        $this->getColumnAliases("wpao_metas")
    )
)
```

##### Notes:

---

You may pass a custom *prefix* as the second argument of the `getColumnAliases(...)` method.